# Trying to trace the time it takes for my website hosted in New Zealand to be accessed from the US

Tags: http, proxy, traceroute

I live in New Zealand and I just started a website which I also have hosted in New Zealand as novazeal.com and novazeal.co.nz. I am hoping to target clients overseas though as well as in New Zealand so I trying to decide whether to start a second website hosted in the US and point the .com domain to that website instead.

I have heard from friends in the States that a site I had hosted here in New Zealand was slow to access, so what I really need to do is get the time it takes for a traceroute to hop through a location in the US. A normal tracert from my computer here will hop through servers in NZ only, so I can't get the measure I am looking for by using a normal tracert. Does anyone know of an alternative I could use such as an application that forces hops through a distant ISP, or a proxy service that gives the time it takes to retrieve a page from a distant location.

Of course if anyone in the States is willing to run the trace for me and send me the hop time stats I would be most grateful. I could ask the friends I mentioned, but they are not particularly technical, so it would probably be a confusing thing to try to explain to them by email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are web-based route tracing utilities, some of which are hosted in the US, that will show you the route and latency between that service and your site (at a point in time).

However, `traceroute` doesn't give you a full picture of the network latency effects to which you're subject: these days routers do all sorts of sophisticated traffic shaping and `traceroute` probes just won't be treated the same as your HTTP traffic *even if* you specify that probes should use TCP and port 80.

Not to mention that network latency itself is just a tiny piece of the puzzle.  ISPs perform all sorts of cacheing using (sometimes transparent) HTTP proxies, from which you won't benefit unless/until your site is visited by their customers.